# display and update database using associative arrays

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, pdo

Elsewhere in my code I have already received input from the user and saved the data to the database.

Now I want to allow the user to update the transaction. Using the following code I display 100 part numbers on the screen (I am only showing a partial snippet). If the $_POST values are valid, I update the table. Otherwise, I allow for user input to update the fields.

pnum  qty 
1 -    3 
2 -    5 
3 -    9 
:

My question is twofold:
(1) If I have 100 part numbers stored on the database, do I need to have 100 if-then-else statements to parse the array data in order to display it on the screen?
(2) Do I also need another 100 if-then-else statements to update the data back to the database table?

```
<?php
  if ( !empty($_POST)) {
$Error_part_no_1 = null;
$Error_part_no_2 = null;
$part_no_1 = $_POST['part_no_1];
$part_no_2 = $_POST['part_no_2];

    if ($valid) {
        $sql = "UPDATE (table)  SET qty = ?";

  } else {
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM (table)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());

while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   if ($row['part_num'] == 'part_no_1' {$part_no_1 = $row['qty'];} 
   if ($row['part_num'] == 'part_no_2' {$part_no_2 = $row['qty'];} 
    }
  }
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($Error_part_no_1)?'error':'';?>">
        <label class="control-label">Part No 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="part_no_1" type="text"  placeholder="" value="<?php echo !empty($part_no_1)?$part_no_1:'';?>">
            <?php if (!empty($Error_part_no_1)): ?>
               <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $Error_part_no_1;?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: *"My question is twofold"* - the answers to both of which are *no* ...

Comment: *aside:* are you ever actually binding anything to that placeholder? `$sql = "UPDATE (table)  SET qty = ?";`

Comment: you realize that you'll be updating your entire database here, unless that's what you want to do.

Comment: `$_POST['part_no_X]` was that a typo?

Comment: `FROM (table)` is that your actual code/syntax? same for `UPDATE (table)` with brackets like that.

Comment: there's also no need to prepare/execute, there's nothing to prepare, just do `query()`.

Comment: @Funky Forty Niner - yes, I see that I have a typo with missing ', sorry. I was trying to make a generic code to show. No the (table) was just abbreviated. I should probably update my code sample so you see what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to mix/match while loops. Ideally, the keys of the arrays should be the PART NUMBER, or unique identifier, which makes it a lot easier to work with. foreach, [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), and while loops are your friend. Something like below:

```
<?php
  if ( !empty($_POST)) {

    if ($valid) {
        //LOOP through $_POST with foreach, update the table accordingly
        foreach ( $_POST as $partNo => $val ) {
            $sql = "UPDATE (table) SET qty = ? WHERE part_no = ?";
            //Execute
        }
  } else {
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM (table)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array());


?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
   <?php while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo in_array($emptyErrors, $row['part_no'])?'error':'';?>">
        <label class="control-label">Part No 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="<?php echo $row['part_no'] ?>" type="text"  placeholder="" value="<?php echo !empty($row['part_no'])?$row['part_no']:'';?>">
            <?php if (in_array($emptyErrors, $row['part_no'])): ?>
               <span class="help-inline">Part number <?php echo $row['part_no'];?> cannot be empty.</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should take another look at their (entire) code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have. It's an inherently hard question to answer without simply providing him/doing all the work for him. I'm trying to guide him in the correct direction.

Comment: [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427544/display-and-update-database-using-associative-arrays#comment83845700_48427544) I left. Wondering if they'll be updating / responding.

Comment: @FrankerZ - thank you for the guidance. I can see that it is quite involved. I will have to stumble through it. Thank you!

Comment: My code is cumbersome. Using arrays as you recommended will simplify my whole process from retrieval, display and update. I have to rethink the way I do it. Thank you

Comment: @VamMeejMub If it worked for you, be sure to mark the answer as accepted, or if not, please edit your original question with more details.

Comment: @FrankerZ - I will accept it since I'm sure it will work. I have to rethink my whole coding process. When I figure it out, I will update my code. Currently I use foreach arrays to echo from the database, but I am struggling to figure how to display into input values that can receive as $_POST from an array and then to update back from the array. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.